# cannot do apt-get update on 12.04, cannot connect to IP

Tags: apt

i cannot update my Ubuntu from terminal or software center and the links work if i go to them manually.

heres the terminal feed.i have to remove the links but they work.

```
Err security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main amd64 Packages
  Unable to connect to 172.25.10.3:80:
.........
.......
........
.......
W: Failed to fetch archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Unable to connect to 172.25.10.3:80:
```

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get` is trying to connect to a local proxy at `172.25.10.3:80`. Were you running some kind of proxy application?

You need to remove this proxy configuration from `apt`. In a terminal, type:

```
cat /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

If this outputs something like this:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://172.25.10.3/";
```

...then this is the culprit file! To fix it, type `sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf` and add a `#` in front of all the lines that contain `172.25.10.3`. When you're done, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save and exit.

Once done, try `sudo apt-get update`.